# What does the keyword strictfp mean?

Tags: java

someone explain what does the keyword `strictfp` mean in the class below?

```
public strictfp class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                double d = 8e+307;
                /** affiche 4 * d /2 donc 2 * d */
                System.out.println(4 * d / 2);
                /** affiche 2 * d */
                System.out.println(2 * d);
        } 
}
```

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam I also find this [What is the strictfp modifier for? When would I consider using it?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=17544)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java strictfp keyword ensures that you will get the same result on every platform if you perform operations in the floating-point variable.The strictfp keyword can be applied on methods, classes and interfaces.

```
strictfp class A{}//strictfp applied on class  
strictfp interface M{}//strictfp applied on interface  
class A{  
strictfp void m(){}//strictfp applied on method  
}
```

The strictfp keyword cannot be applied on abstract methods, variables or constructors.

```
class B{  
strictfp abstract void m();//Illegal combination of modifiers  
}  
class B{  
strictfp int data=10;//modifier strictfp not allowed here  
}  
class B{  
strictfp B(){}//modifier strictfp not allowed here  
}
```

Comment: thnx but what does floating-point variable mean ?

Comment: @hulk, a floating point variable is a variable which can store numbers lik 2.6, 8.430, 0.086, and so on. Basically, it can store numbers which have decimals in them.